# Symfony 3 service configuration providing dynamic configuration

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I would like to know how I could avoid setter injection under the following use case.

I have a collection of tagged services:

```
interface EmailFormatter

class CvEmailFormatter implements EmailFormatter
class RegistrationEmailFormatter implements EmailFormatter
class LostPasswordEmailFormatter implements EmailFormatter
```

I use a CompilerPass to inject these into a mailer service by invoking its **addEmailFormatter()** method.

Each EmailFormatter instance requires some configuration that must be retrieved at run time from the current user:

```
/**
 * @var FormatterConfig[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\FormatterConfig", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $formatterConfigs;
```

Right now I am checking to see if the user has created a configuration for a particular EmailFormatter inside the mailer service's **addEmailFormatter()** method. If they have then **setConfig()** injects the configuration object. If no config exists yet the EmailFormatter does not get added at all.

```
public function addEmailFormatter(EmailFormatter $formatter, $alias)
{
    $formatterConfig = $this->user->getFormatterConfig($alias);

    if (null !== $formatterConfig) {
        $this->formatters[$alias] = $formatter;
        $formatter->setConfig($formatterConfig);
    }
}
```

Could this be a legitimate use case given I am working with a mutable collection of services?

Comment: What is the problem? What is the error or condition you're trying to avoid? Why don't you want to use this current setup?

Comment: My question is in relation to the fairly widespread advice that setter injection is bad practice.